# Remove <title> wordpress tag or?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am using a wordpress theme called Kalium along with some modified parts for my site here: https://www.idee-creative.co.uk

I have added custom fields on every page type so I can easily add my own title and description tags so they are customisable on each and every page. The code I have used for that is here:

```
<title><?php the_field('seo_page_title'); ?></title>
<meta name="description" content="<?php the_field('seo_page_description'); ?>"/>
```

Pulling in the custom fields and displaying them in the header of my pages.

The trouble I am having is that, when I look at the source code of a page, Wordpress seems to add it's own  tag. So my site has two  tags. I would prefer to keep my own customised ones and get remove the Wordpress version.

I can't seem to find where they are coming from, I've checked my header.php file and there doesn't seem to be anything pulling the title tag in apart from my own custom code above... Here's the complete header.php code if it helps:

```
<?php
/**
 *  Kalium WordPress Theme
 *
 *  Laborator.co
 *  www.laborator.co
 */

// Get Menu Type To Use
$main_menu_type = get_data( 'main_menu_type' );
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" <?php language_attributes(); ?>> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html <?php language_attributes(); ?>> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title><?php the_field('seo_page_title'); ?></title>
    <meta name="description" content="<?php the_field('seo_page_description'); ?>"/>

    <!-- Inclide Schema Markup File
    –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
    <?php include('json-ld.php'); ?><script type="application/ld+json"><?php echo json_encode($payload); ?></script>


    <?php wp_head(); ?>


</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

    <?php
    if ( apply_filters( 'kalium_show_header', true ) ) :

        // Theme Borders
        if ( get_data( 'theme_borders' ) ) :

            get_template_part( 'tpls/borders' );

        endif;

        // Mobile Menu
        include locate_template( 'tpls/menu-mobile.php' );

        // Top Menu
        if ( $main_menu_type == 'top-menu' || get_data( 'menu_top_force_include' ) ) {
            include locate_template( 'tpls/menu-top.php' );
        }

        // Sidebar Menu
        if ( $main_menu_type == 'sidebar-menu' || get_data( 'menu_sidebar_force_include' ) ) {
            include locate_template( 'tpls/menu-sidebar.php' );
        }

    endif;
    ?>

    <div class="wrapper" id="main-wrapper">

        <?php
        // Kalium Start Wrapper
        do_action( 'kalium_wrapper_start' );    

        // Show Header
        if ( apply_filters( 'kalium_show_header', true ) ):

            // Main Header
            get_template_part( 'tpls/header-main' );

        endif;
        ?>
```

++++++++++++UPDATE++++++++++++

This is the function I have found that creates the title I believe... Its in a hidden away include file in the parent theme...

```
    // Open Graph Meta
function kalium_wp_head_open_graph_meta() {
    global $post;

    // Only show if open graph meta is allowed
    if ( ! apply_filters( 'kalium_open_graph_meta', true ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Do not show open graph meta on single posts
    if ( ! is_singular() ) {
        return;
    }

    $featured_image = $post_thumb_id = '';

    if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) {
        $post_thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
        $featured_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumb_id, 'original' );
    }

    // Excerpt, clean styles
    $excerpt = kalium_clean_excerpt( get_the_excerpt(), true );

    ?>

    <meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_title() ); ?>"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ); ?>"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo esc_attr( $excerpt ); ?>"/>

    <?php if ( is_array( $featured_image ) ) : ?>
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $featured_image[0]; ?>"/>
    <link itemprop="image" href="<?php echo $featured_image[0]; ?>" />

        <?php if ( apply_filters( 'kalium_meta_google_thumbnail', true ) ) : $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumb_id, 'thumbnail' ); ?>
        <!--
          <PageMap>
            <DataObject type="thumbnail">
              <Attribute name="src" value="<?php echo $thumb[0]; ?>"/>
              <Attribute name="width" value="<?php echo $thumb[1]; ?>"/>
              <Attribute name="height" value="<?php echo $thumb[2]; ?>"/>
            </DataObject>
          </PageMap>
        -->
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endif;
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'kalium_wp_head_open_graph_meta', 5 );
```

++++++++++++ UPDATE 2 ++++++++++++

Sorry for the constant updates, but I also have this in another part of the theme:

```
// Title Parts
function kalium_wp_title_parts( $title, $sep, $seplocation ) {
    $kalium_separator = apply_filters( 'kalium_wp_title_separator', ' &ndash; ' );

    if ( empty( $sep ) ) {
        return $title;
    }

    $title_sep = explode( $sep, $title );

    if ( ! is_array( $title_sep ) ) {
        return $title;
    }

    if ( $seplocation == 'right' ) {
        $title = str_replace( $sep . end( $title_sep ), $kalium_separator . end( $title_sep ), $title );
    } else {
        $title = str_replace( reset( $title_sep ) . $sep, reset( $title_sep ) . $kalium_separator, $title );
    }

    return $title;
}

add_filter( 'wp_title', 'kalium_wp_title_parts', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: comment out <?php wp_head(); ?>

Comment: Why are you using a custom field for the page title in the first place? Why are you replicating fields that already exist?

Comment: did you try with `add_filter( 'wp_title',`?

Comment: As your way is seems the correct way to manipulate page title. but however you can try to return empty string from wp_title function inside wp-includes/general-template.php

Comment: CBroe - Because it gives me the option to change the title format and enebales me to add custom page titles for each page. Feel free to suggest an alternative?

Comment: user1544541 - I thought that <?php wp_head(); ?> was really important for other aspects of Wordpress so I didn't want delete that? or would it be fine to remove?

Comment: vel - Where would I try with the add_filter? should that be in the functions file? Sorry I don't understand what you mean...

Comment: I've actually found a page-heading file ill update the ticket with - Would the title be in here?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [wp_title](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_title/) hook
like so :

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'my_custom_title_function', 20 );
```

and then just define the function

```
function my_custom_title_function( $title ) {
   // use own function to produce title, for example:
   //  return str_replace('Old title', 'New title', $title); 
}
```

or in your case it might be for example:

```
function my_custom_title_function( $title ) {
return the_field('seo_page_title');
}
```

( assuming `the_field` is a valid and available function at that stage.  )

if you want to totally remove the `<title>` tag :

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', '_wp_render_title_tag', 1 );
```

Or in a simpler way (a child theme,)

`remove_theme_support( 'title-tag' )`

You can also use `wp_head` with `ob_start` and such, but not recommended ..

**After op edit :**

If there is another filter , just remove it ..

```
remove_filter( 'wp_title', 'kalium_wp_title_parts', 99); / or 1
```

I also suggest you read a bit about wp actions, filters and hooks . it's fundamental for wp development ..

Comment: That's excellent, thank you!

I will try and customise it first before removing it. 

I assume this would all go n the functions.php file?

Comment: By default yes, but it can actually go anywhere ( e.g. plugin..) . Also, if that has resolved your issue it would be good to accept the answer to somehow mark as solved ..

Comment: Hi, of course, It's all sound code, but it still doesn't work I'm afraid. If you look above I've based in the function that I think generates the title tag, this was an include in the parent theme's functions file, inside another folder called 'inc' - So I assume I can put something in my functions file to disable that function?